# Ignoring case in spark while joining

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe(**input_dataframe_1**), data in this dataframe looks like as below:

```
id              value
 1                Ab
 2                Ai
 3                aB
```

I have another spark dataframe(**input_dataframe_2**), data in this dataframe looks like as below:

```
name              value
 x                ab
 y                iA
 z                aB
```

I want to join both dataframe and join condition should be case insensitive, below is the join condition I am using:

```
output = input_dataframe_1.join(input_dataframe_2,['value'])
```

How can I make join condition case insensitive?

Answer (score 4):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import lower

#sample data
input_dataframe_1 = sc.parallelize([(1, 'Ab'), (2, 'Ai'), (3, 'aB')]).toDF(["id", "value"])
input_dataframe_2 = sc.parallelize([('x', 'ab'), ('y', 'iA'), ('z', 'aB')]).toDF(["name", "value"])

output = input_dataframe_1.\
    join(input_dataframe_2, lower(input_dataframe_1.value)==lower(input_dataframe_2.value)).\
    drop(input_dataframe_2.value)
output.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Expecting you are doing an inner join, find below solution:

#### Create input dataframe 1

```
val inputDF1 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("1","Ab"),("2","Ai"),("3","aB"))).withColumnRenamed("_1","id").withColumnRenamed("_2","value")
```

#### Create input dataframe 2

```
val inputDF2 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("x","ab"),("y","iA"),("z","aB"))).withColumnRenamed("_1","id").withColumnRenamed("_2","value")
```

#### Joining both dataframes on lower(value) column

```
inputDF1.join(inputDF2,lower(inputDF1.col("value"))===lower(inputDF2.col("value"))).show
```

| id | value | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ab | z | aB |
| 1 | Ab | x | ab |
| 3 | aB | z | aB |
| 3 | aB | x | ab |

Comment: your answer is written in `scala`. The OP tagged the question `#pyspark`.
A `scala` version may be beneficial, but a `python`-based version may be more likely to meet the OP's needs.

Comment: Thats true.. However Spark Dataframe operations should be independent of programming language.